# Does Googlebot crawl url with get parameters?

Tags: mod-rewrite, web-crawler

I gave up rewriting url because I don't feel the necessity.

So url looks like "http://www.stackoverflow.com?question=35453."

But, I worry about one thing.

Does Googlebot crawl my pages?

Do I need to rewrite my url like "http://www.stackoverflow.com/question/35453"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Googlebot crawl my pages?
Yes. But you can set in google webmaster tools to ignore it.
In a general way, if you want nice url more meaningful for search engines and users, you should avoid parameters and transform to human language words separated by dashes.

So IMHO, the best you could do is:
`http://www.stackoverflow.com/question/does-googlebot-crawl-url-with-get-parameters.html`.